# I'd like my popup images to be fully on the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a spreadsheet-like webpage where one column is one or more names of jpg files. When the mouse hovers over a name a thumbnail pops up on the left side of the link. This works fine, but when the entry is at the bottom of the viewport the popup appears nearly off the bottom, with only the top showing. Is there a way using css to have the popup image move north so it is fully visible? (and the same question for left-right scrolling) I suppose I could hack something with javascript, but is there a CSS way o do this?

Here is the css:

```
        .popup-im-wrap {
            position: relative;
        }
        .popup-im span { 
            position:absolute;
            visibility:hidden;
        }
        .popup-im:hover, .popup-im:hover span {
            visibility:visible;
            z-index:7;
        }
        .popup-im span img {
            max-width: 200px;
            max-height: 200px;
        }

        .popup-im:hover span {
            left: 0%;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            top: calc(100% + 10px);
        }
```

The HTML is generated, but each entry looks like this:

```
<td>
  <span class="popup-im-wrap">
    <a class="popup-im" href="images/xxx.jpg" target="full-image">xxx.jpg
      <span>
        <img src="images/xxx.jpg"alt="image xxx.jpg" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
```